# How to remove 'clear all' button with CSS (ng-select field)

Tags: css, button, angular6

How do I remove the "clear button" from a ng-select field with search?

[image]
I'm using angular 6 with ng-select package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your stylesheet add `display: none;` to the `.ng-clear-wrapper` selector.

Like so:

```
.ng-select .ng-clear-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: accepted but as per the first answer the official way is

[clearable]="false"

Answer (score 38):

Add `[clearable]="false"` attribute to your `ng-select tab`

Example:

```
<ng-select class="disable-clear-all" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do this. The other method is just a CSS hack and could be added in easily via editing css on runtime

Comment: The asker _did_ ask how to do it with css though. But in most use cases I agree with you that this would be much cleaner, whereas the css fix is clearly a hack.